# Marking positions with decoration using arrowhead

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-arrows, tikz-decorations

Hello helpful and knowledgeable community.

I come to you again with a puzzle :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}% dessin
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\usepackage[straightvoltages, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1,line width=1 pt
,decoration={
markings,% switch on markings
mark=at position .6 with {\arrowreversed[]{Latex[length=0.3cm]}} } %\arrowreversed
]

\draw[postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[pos=0.6,above,scale=2] {i} ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

This MWE gives : [image]

As you can see the arrow as an offset to the right compared to the `i`, and ideally I would like it like that :
(without having to tweak it by hand)

[image]

I also tried another way : using in my code

```
mark=at position .6 with {\arrowreversed[]{Latex[length=0.3cm]},\node[anchor=south,scale=2] {i}; 
}
```

And it still gives :

[image]

I would like to know if could place the arrowhead with its center (as if using `anchor=center`) and I am open to other suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please make your code compilable. A MWE is always a complete compilable example starting with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and  have \end{document}.

Comment: I had forgotten indeed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Arrows are drawn, so that the tip ends at the given coordinate. You can use `sep` to adjust their position. `sep=-0.15cm -1` means move the arrow head 0.15 cm(half the `length`) and an additional line width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.markings, arrows.meta}
\usepackage[straightvoltages, siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
line width=1pt,
decoration={
markings,% switch on markings
mark=at position .6 with {\arrowreversed[]{Latex[length=0.3cm, sep=-0.15cm -1]}} } %\arrowreversed
]
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[pos=0.6,above, scale=2] {i} ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: line with arrow head and the letter "i"]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you tell me why you need the "-1" ? I have tried and it seems to offset the "i", the bigger "line width" is defined, the bigger the offset, until the "i" is no longer above the arrow head.

Comment: It is all about the visual appearance. Do not trust the position of the `i`. Add this `\draw[red] ({0.6*3},0) circle[radius=1pt]; \draw[red] ({0.6*3+0.3},0) circle[radius=1pt];` and try with `sep=0`. You are probably correct that making `sep` dependent on line with is wrong. I do not know your use case, but normally one would *not* hardcode line width (use e.g. `thick`) and make arrow head dependent on line width - `length=0cm 5`.